# Netbeans cannot install plugins directly

Tags: upgrade, plugins, netbeans

Last night, I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. As part of the process, Netbeans upgraded from version 8.1 to version 10.0. The PHP plugin stopped working: my code has no highlighting. Following advice I found, i uninstalled and reinstalled the plugin. Or, at least, I uninstalled it. Reinstalling it is proving more difficult.

When I select the PHP plugin from the list of available plugins, I am told that it will install the PHP plugin and five other plugins that it depends on. In actual fact, it attempts to download loads of plugins, and *it always fails*. It downloads a few (approx. 35), and then gives me an error message of the form:

> Networking problem in https://netbeans.apache.org/nb/updates/10.0/webcommon/org-netbeans-modules-javascript-v8debug.nbm
>
> Check your proxy settings or try again later. The server may be unavailable at the moment. You may also want to make sure that your firewall is not blocking network traffic. Your cache may be out of date. Please click Check for Updates to refresh content.

Each time, the URL works, and I can download and install the plugin manually. I can then try the PHP plugin again, and it will again download about 35 plugins before throwing another error, which again I can download manually. I suppose eventually I'll get to the end of this, and the PHP plugin will be installed, but it's very frustrating. I've now manually installed about 15 plugins, with no end in sight yet.

Two questions:

- What's causing this problem, and how can I fix it? (I don't have a proxy or a firewall, and I have checked for updates.)
- Will the manually installed plugins update correctly when updates are available? I'm worried that because they were installed manually instead of through the usual installer, they'll be disconnected from the update mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a problem getting Plug-Ins to install and NetBeans updates to work on my Netbeans installation (*under 64bit Ubuntu 16.04*), and finally stumbled across a functional answer from this thead:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664874/netbeans-update-fail

Basically, I had to go to **Tools --> Plugins --> Settings** , select each entry from the left, and click the **Edit** button on the right and change the URL of each entry from http:// to https://  as shown here:

[Settings Tab in Plugins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j15wr.png)

After doing that, I was able to successfully update everything and install plugins through NetBeans.

Comment: I gave up on Netbeans after this and switched to VS Code, but there are some things I miss about Netbeans. I may give this a try. Thanks.

Comment: I'm forced to use Netbeans for one of my projects at work and it's not too bad.  Hopefully this solution will fix your problem, as it did for me.  I use VS Code a lot for other projects, and I like it, but I'm old enough to still be freaked out using a Microsoft editor on a Linux computer....

Comment: It weirds me out too, knowing that it's a Microsoft editor, and it's not as good as Netbeans is at code completion in PHP. It doesn't understand variable scope, and it doesn't understand that `public $v_name` is related to `$this->v_name`.